# Black screen in OBS Studio screencast on Linux

Tags: linux, amd-radeon, screencasts, obs-studio

I'm trying to make a screencast (Screen capture XSHM) in OBS Studio on my Fedora 31 computer. However it shows only black screen with mouse cursor on it. I also tried "Window Capture (Xcomposite)" however in this case the "Window" drop down shows only few application windows, while what I need (terminal, browser) is missing. Other screencasting tools like SimpleScreenRecorder and Vokoscreen experience the same issue (note that I don't run them simultaneously).

There are some advices in Internet how to solve this problem via NVidia Control Panel. However my laptop does not have NVidia graphics card. There is only a built-in Radeon Vega card.

This is my system configuration:

```
          /:-------------:\          user@hostname 
       :-------------------::        -------- 
     :-----------/shhOHbmp---:\      OS: Fedora 31 (Workstation Edition) x86_64 
   /-----------omMMMNNNMMD  ---:     Host: ThinkPad T495 
  :-----------sMMMMNMNMP.    ---:    Kernel: 5.4.7-200.fc31.x86_64 
 :-----------:MMMdP-------    ---\   Uptime: 17 mins 
,------------:MMMd--------    ---:   Packages: 5943 (rpm), 1 (flatpak) 
:------------:MMMd-------    .---:   Shell: bash 5.0.11 
:----    oNMMMMMMMMMNho     .----:   Resolution: 1920x1080, 1920x1080 
:--     .+shhhMMMmhhy++   .------/   DE: GNOME 3.34.2 
:-    -------:MMMd--------------:    Theme: Adwaita [GTK2/3] 
:-   --------/MMMd-------------;     Icons: Adwaita [GTK2/3] 
:-    ------/hMMMy------------:      Terminal: gnome-terminal 
:-- :dMNdhhdNMMNo------------;       CPU: AMD Ryzen 5 PRO 3500U w/ Radeon Vega  
:---:sdNMMMMNds:------------:        GPU: AMD ATI 06:00.0 Picasso 
:------:://:-------------::          Memory: 2239MiB / 21972MiB 
:---------------------://
```

Answer (score 2):

The workaround that I have found is in disabling Wayland.

Open */etc/gdm/custom.conf* and uncomment line

```
WaylandEnable=false
```

After the computer restart everything works fine.